Connect 3 existing semantic model as a source for a PBI report
I'm a power bi administrator facing issue with the performance of a report.
The user has a report which connects 3 existing semantic models in power bi service.The user doesn't want to load the data again as, data which he needs is already in the power bi service.He achieved this using analysis service and build the report.
But, this report is consuming high memory from our premium capacity and often enables auto-scaling which indeed causing extra cost.
Is there any better method to connect these semantic models and build a report which won't consume the memory as analysis service does?
The reports which causing peaks when combined together with the analysis service are not causing any issue while we refresh it individually. I have checked the fabrics metric app for this and confirmed.
connected the workspace with log analytics and found that analysis service is cross joining the column in each table and thus the refresh time and memory consumption is increased.
Can someone suggest a better way to connect these 3 datasets and build a report in power bi?

See Use composite models in Power BI Desktop

@SamNseir I think the user is using composite mode now and it is causing performance issues. Is there any other method that the user can imply?

Is the memory hit during dataset refresh (import) or at report run time (DirectQuery)?

@SamNseir At the refresh time. Report is just refreshing once a day, at that time its causing memory hit. Report is really quick and no memory hits are noticed yet.

So the user is importing all the data from the three datasets? Suggestion is to look at the link above again and see if they can achieve the same with DirectQuery.

@SamNseir Sure will check with them.But when i first noticed this memory hit, i checked with the user and he mentioned it was due to DirectQuery connection. Later he said he shifted it into import mode. So i assume even with direct query there maybe some issue .So in that case is there any other methods to achieve it?
